# notify_url with multiple items in paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I have a form to pay with paypal, which generates the items in a for loop. I need, on the notify_url page, to access the order data to save them in the database. I have it done for 2 items but I need to do it for the number of items that the for generates.

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscra" method="post" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sb-pwrdu1932120@business.example.com" />
    <?php
    for($i=1;$i<7;$i++)
    {
    echo("<input type='hidden' name='quantity_".$i."' value='1'/>");
    echo("<input type='hidden' name='item_name_".$i."' value='articulo".$i."'/>");
    echo("<input type='hidden' name='item_number_".$i."' value='".$i."' />");
    echo("<input type='hidden' name='amount_".$i."' value='1' />");
    }
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://infrangible-discoun.000webhostapp.com/plantillas/return.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" >
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://infrangible-discoun.000webhostapp.com/plantillas/return.php">  
    <input type="submit" id="pagar" name="pagar" value="PayPal">
    </body>
</html>
```

notifyUrl.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    require("conexion.php");
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    /*$data['item_name']          = $_POST['item_name'];
    $data['item_number']        = $_POST['item_number'];
    $data['payment_status']     = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $data['payment_amount']     = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $data['payment_currency']   = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $data['txn_id']             = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $data['receiver_email']     = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $data['payer_email']        = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $data['custom']             = $_POST['custom'];
    $data['invoice']            = $_POST['invoice'];
    $data['paypallog']          = $req;*/
    $name=$_POST['item_name1'];
    $name2=$_POST['item_name2'];
    mysqli_query($db,"insert into ventas value(0,'$name')");
    mysqli_query($db,"insert into ventas value(0,'$name2')");
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So many security and reliability problems in the above, not to mention the legacy checkout experience. Rather than go into detail about everything that's poor about this solution, I recommend you start from scratch with a proper server-side integration of PayPal Checkout. Some details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65271890/2069605

Comment: I am only doing tests, I am satisfied with knowing how to do it for n items.